# View image in different resolution screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, image

I have to put a picture in my application. Not to make her see evil on Android devices with different resolutions is enough to put it into different folders (mdpi etc.) or are there other things to do? What is the resolution for each folder?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Android developer guide [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) to see some really good info on supporting screen sizes.

One approach is to use the different resource/drawable folders you have alluded to (ldpi, mdpi etc.), which are referenced as follows:

> - xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
> - large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
> - normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
> - small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

As I mentioned, there are a number of other ways to handle screen resolutions and I would suggest you find the one that suits you best (check [this](http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf) one out!).

Place the different image sizes in the different folders with the same name, and when you reference them in code, Android will choose the best match.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Consider MDPI images as baseline following are the resolutions that should be:

**Folder**  **Image ratio**   **size example**

ldpi  -     MDPI x 0.75   -     75px

MDPI   -   100       -          100px

HDPI   -   MDPI x 1.5  -        150px

XHDPI   -  MDPI x 2.0    -      200px

Comment: Excuse me, which should be the resolutions for each folder? For example 300x250 etc.

Comment: android screens are 240x320, 320x480, 480x800, 720x1280 for LDPI, MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI respectively.